# Finding Bluetooth RSSI Value In Visual C++ Win 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio, bluetooth, windows-10, rssi

I have done a lot of researching about this stuff but could not get clear answer. I found the bluetooth device's name and NAP and SAP addresses with `WSALookupServiceNext(...)`  function but can't access the RSSI value. Is there specific function or something else that i can use the find the RSSI value?

PS: `BthReadRSSI` function requires extra library that could not found on internet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ee495452(v=winembedded.80)#requirements

```
while (WSALookupServiceNext(hLookup, LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_ADDR, &dwSize, pwsaResults) == 0)
{
    btAddr = ((SOCKADDR_BTH *)pwsaResults->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr)->btAddr;

    // Verify the returned name

    bHaveName = (pwsaResults->lpszServiceInstanceName) && *(pwsaResults->lpszServiceInstanceName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TO get RSSI value on Win 10 you must use WinRT API. Also your device must be connected somehow.

The native C++ code that uses WinRT to red RSSI is too long to publish it here.

The easy way is to use thrid party library. For example [Bluetooth Framework](http://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). Or if you would like contact me by Skype (mike.petrichenko). I can not promise that I give you ready solution but I can guid you into right direction so you can get your own code.